# How to force British Summer Time (UTC+1) when using dates in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = d.getHours() + ':' + d.getMinutes();
```

When I view the code in a browser from my home in London, I see the UTC+1 time:

```
<div id="time">01:07</div>
```

I'm pretty sure I see UTC+1 time because it is the time of my system's clock. For somebody viewing the code in Florida, the time would read 20:07 (UTC-4).

How can I force the time output to be UTC+1 for everyone?

Comment: You might want to look into [moment-timezone.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) which has is a JS library with some fancy timezone-handling capabilities.

Comment: I was thinking about using the moment-timezone.js library but would like to try to understand how to do this using JS if possible.

Comment: I agree with the momentjs comment, we use it in production, its a great help.

Comment: Maybe watching [this YouTube video from Computerphile about dealing with timezones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY) will convince you to use a 3rd party library. :)

Comment: OK at about 3:26s into the video I've decided I'm using moment.js :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [moment.js timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)

```
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = moment().tz('Europe/London').format('HH:mm');
```